# What kind of encoding is used in url?

Tags: url, encoding

Sometimes I saw some escape character sequence started with `%` in url, for example,

> https://images-blogger-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url=http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-yFH04SzTbeA%2FVPNvFAE04MI...

I wonder what is the kind of encoding called?

Why is it used, instead of directly using the characters they represent?

How can I

- separate them from other characters?
- find out what they  represent?

Thanks.

Comment: It's called [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Percent enconding, it is defined on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1

In python you can decode it using [urllib.unquote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote)

```py
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote('http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-yFH04SzTbeA%2FVPNvFAE04MI')
'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-yFH04SzTbeA/VPNvFAE04MI'
```

And in javascript you can use [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape):

```js
unescape('http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-yFH04SzTbeA%2FVPNvFAE04MI')
"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-yFH04SzTbeA/VPNvFAE04MI"
```